# Python nested try/except blocks, checking the date

Tags: python

I think I have some wrong understanding of how try/except blocks work in python.

What I am getting as an input is date in YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM or YYYY format. What I need is to check is what was delivered exactly(whether I have only a day or month+day or a full date).

```
def check(date_text):
  year_delivered = True
  month_delivered = True
  day_delivered = True
  try:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d')
  except ValueError:
    day_delivered = False
    try:
      date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m')
    except ValueError:
      month_delivered = False
      try:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y')
      except ValueError:
        year_delivered = False 
  return year_delivered, month_delivered, day_delivered
```

I've wanted to check it using datetime and flags. So from my understanding, first two try/except blocks should raise an exception when `date_text = "2018"` and change the value of day and month flags. However, they remain True and I don't quite understand why.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  `check('2018')` returns `(True, False, False)` for me when I run your code, as it should.

Comment: You can also try dateparser: https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for general-purpose datetime parsing.